# Fake proof that $1=0$ using the product law for limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, fake-proofs

**Context:**  I was looking at [Is it true that $0.999999999\ldots=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-ldots-1) Then I started thinking: if $0.999999... = 1$, then $0.000..001 = 1/1000...000 = 0$. Then if we multiply both side by $1000...000$, we will have $1 = 0$?

To rephrase it in a slightly more formal way as below. Suppose we multiply both sides of the equality
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0$$
by $n$:
\begin{align}
n \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}&=n\cdot 0 \\[5pt]
\lim_{n \to \infty}1 &= 0
\end{align}
So $1=0$. I'm sure I am wrong, but what exactly is wrong with my reasoning?

**Edit** After some kind suggestion and answers from Terasa, Martin and Joe, I'd like to link a related helpful question below. The only slight difference is that question confused about the infinite sum and limits, while I confused between the product and limits!

[What is wrong with the argument $1 = \lim_{n\to \infty} n/n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1/n+1/n+\dotsb+1/n) = 0 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3780430/what-is-wrong-with-the-argument-1-lim-n-to-infty-n-n-lim-n-to-infty?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: $g(n) \lim f(n) \ne \lim [ f(n) g(n)] $ generally.

Comment: how can you take $ n$ inside limit?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124760/discussion-on-question-by-matt-frank-fake-proof-that-10-using-the-product-law).

Comment: I'm very pleased that you have improved your question. I'm sure your contributions will be very welcome here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, we have the limit law
$$
k\lim_{n \to \infty}f(n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}kf(n) \, ,
$$
where $k$ is any constant (provided, of course, that the limit exists). However, it does not make sense to write
$$
n\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}1 \, .
$$
The reason for this is quite subtle: the $n$ inside the limit operator is a *dummy variable*. The only purpose it is serving is to tell us that we are finding the limit of the function $f$ given by $f(x)=1/x$. The $n$ outside the limit operator is not a dummy variable.* So your confusion is occurring because of a notational conflict. If you write the limit as
$$
n\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{x} \, ,
$$
where you are no longer using $n$ in two different ways, then we do indeed have
$$
n\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{n}{x}
$$
for any real number $n$. But this does not imply that $1=0$.

---

*One way to check whether a variable is a 'dummy' is to consider whether you can substitute a value in for it. If you consider the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{n}{x}
$$
then it makes sense to plug in $n=5$, say, but plugging in $x=5$ would be absurd. That's because $1/x$ represents a function. More formally, it can be viewed as a shorthand for the function $f$ such that
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{x}
$$
for all $x\neq0$.

Answer (score 0):

The Product Law of limits allows you to split the limit of product into two components only when they exist. In this case$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\times\frac{1}{n}\ne\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\times\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$ because $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\rightarrow\infty$$ does not exist. So there is no violation or inconsistency just that the product rule which you are trying to apply is itself not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply both sides by $n$, you get the left hand side equal to

$$n\cdot \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\right) = n\cdot 0 = 0$$

and the right hand side is equal to

$$n\cdot 0 = 0$$

so there is no contradiction.