# limit $\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n+\cdots+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n}_{n\text{ times}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, recreational-mathematics, paradoxes

Basically this: [1 = 0 with limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbMIg.png)
\begin{align}
1&=\lim_{n\to\infty} 1\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac n n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\underbrace{\frac1n + \frac1n + \cdots +\frac1n}_{n\text{ times}}\right)\\
&=\underbrace{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n+\cdots+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n}_{n\text{ times}}\\
&=\underbrace{0+0+\cdots+0}_{n\text{ times}}\\
&=0
\end{align}

Can anyone please help me find the mistake?

I know it's related to that "infinite sum" inside the brackets because it should be equal to 1, would that mean we're calculating a double limit?

Thanks!

btw, "veces" means times, and at the beginning it basically says: "what's the error"

Comment: The fourth equality is incorrect: the multiple rule $\displaystyle(\lim_{n\to\infty} kf(n)=k\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$ for real $k)$ doesn't apply for multiples that depend on $n.$

Comment: the error is in the distribution of the limit to the sum of $\frac{\}{n}$, you forget that you are also taking the limit as the number of summations goes to infinity

Comment: Passing from the $3^{rd}$ to the $5^{th}$ line is equivalent to $\displaystyle\,\lim_{n\to\infty} \,\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \,\sum_{k=1}^n \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\,$ which has no good reason to hold true, and it does not.

Comment: I think everyone is trying to say the same thing. I would say it's like saying $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\frac 1n = \infty\cdot0=0$, which is not true as the zero in the $\infty\cdot0$ is not the absolute zero, but it's still approaching to zero, so $\infty\cdot0\ne0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fake proof that $1=0$ using the product law for limits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4152921/fake-proof-that-1-0-using-the-product-law-for-limits)

Comment: Sum of the limits is not same as limit of sums, or more generally limit of a function is not function of a limit.

Comment: @ryang Indeed, it is helpful for the OP to look at the fallacy from multiple angles.

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac nn \neq \lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n$$

Comment: That's why they are trivially not equal.

Comment: That is the flaw in the fake proof above,  replacing "N times" in the underbraces section with multiplication by n

Comment: But it is not an equality?

Comment: @Naren Point is that the "things" on the two sides of the $\ne$ sign cannot be compared, because the RHS contains an $n$ which is nowhere defined.

Comment: @dxiv The way you have commented is not the way he went from step 3 to 4, he didn't use a lim in from of his summation. What you showed is a more reasonable next step that he didn't take. He wrote something that doesn't parse. My answer is equally absurd but to me more obviously absurd and his was subtly absurd. A distinction that makes it more clear.

Comment: @Naren Did you intend the way I edited?

Comment: @dxiv Makes sense. I will keep the edit.

Comment: @Naren "*he didn't use a lim in from of his summation*" $\;-\;$ The $\,\dots\,$ stand for an implied limit there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 4):

The *fourth* equality $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(n\left(\frac1n\right)\right)
=n\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\right)\tag{*}$$ is incorrect:

- the multiple rule $$\lim_{n\to\infty} kf(n)=k\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)
     \quad\text{for }k\in\mathbb R$$ is inapplicable because the multiple
  $k$ does not depend on $n$ (so, $k$ cannot be $n$);
- the product rule $$\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)f(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}
     g(n)\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)$$ is also inapplicable because all the limits
  must exist (so, $g(n)$ cannot be $n,$ and
  $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ne n).$

Notice also that $(*)$ is equivalent to $$\lim_{m\to\infty} \left(m\left(\frac1m\right)\right)
=n\left(\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1m\right),$$ and that $$\exists n\;\lim_{m\to\infty} \left(m\left(\frac1m\right)\right)
=n\left(\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac1m\right)$$ is a false statement.